# Cant get logging element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

When i was testing my program, it's end with code 1

- here is full error (`"Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\ds072\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 20, in <module> wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input"))).send_keys("my username"`)")
- here is my code (https://pastebin.com/RThnY8GY)
  I have tested alternatives for this value (`"/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input"`) but with out results :C
  [image: element witch i was trying to get]

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way to select those fields and login into that website (fields are in an iframe):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")
webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

url = 'https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/synergia/loguj'
browser.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class = "btn btn-third btn-synergia-top btn-navbar dropdown-toggle"]'))).click()
print('clicked to open dropdown') 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/rodzina/synergia/loguj"]'))).click()
print('clicked to get the login interface') 
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='caLoginIframe']")))
print('switched to iframe')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="Login"]'))).send_keys('My username')
print('located and wrote into id field')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="Pass"]'))).send_keys('My password')
print('located and wrote into password field')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="LoginBtn"]'))).click()
print('logging in now...')
```

This will also print in terminal:

```
clicked to open dropdown
clicked to get the login interface
switched to iframe
located and wrote into id field
located and wrote into password field
```

Selenium setup is linux/chrome, you can adapt the code to your own setup, just observe the imports and code after defining the browser.

For Selenium documentation, please see https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/